# Considering hybrid monopropellants like NOFBX to replace current toxic bipropellants and for boost

Tags: rockets, propulsion

Hydrazine/tetroxide is already contaminating the outside of the ISS and clinging to astronaut space suits. It can create breathing problems. In addition, a monopropellant vastly simplifies maneuvering jets and in the case of NOFBX simplifies long term storage and handling both in space and on the ground. It can also self-pressurize, again reducing the complexity of systems using it.

As far as I understand, it can achieve ISP's in excess of 300. This would seem to qualify it for boosters. Also, it has a fairly high specific density, making it to have a dual advantage...less tankage and plumbing from being a monopropellant and less tankage from being dense. All tests so far indicate that it burns at lower temperatures, making it less demanding on nozzles...reusability anyone.

For boost, I doubt that it could be self-pressurizing, but one pump instead of two seems desirable. Also, having a single source or at least single fuel type for both propulsion and maneuvering would seem to be a huge advantage. What am I missing here?

For reference, you can refer to the wiki articles on NOFBX and mixed monopropellants and from the former to the company currently developing NOFBX. It should be noted that NASA has approved an engine using NOFBX for attachment to the ISS, meaning that it has already passed a rather high safety bar.

Comment: I think VASIMR is probably a better candidate for ISS boost.

Comment: What is actually the question? If Progress / ATV vehicles and the Zvezda module will / would / should move from hydrazine based bipropellants to nitrous oxide fuel blend monopropellants? Or if any future vehicles / modules offering ISS orbital reboost capability will use NOFBX? The former obviously won't happen. The latter, nobody really knows when even the station's near future is a touchy-feely business and even all the contenders for the NASA's Commercial Resupply Services 2 aren't decided yet. And that's just the US side of things. There's also Russia, Europe, and Japan.

Comment: Please edit to make your actual question stand out.